# Delphi+interbase. Не закрывается транзакция

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые программисты, ситуация следующая:

Написал приложение на Delphi 7 (подключаюсь к базе, просматриваю данные, вношу новые данные - всё хорошо), однако, если я запускаю моё приложение дважды, то данные, которые я добавил из первого приложения не отображаются во втором, хотя select запрос повесил под таймер.

Никогда не сталкивался подобной этой ситуацией, при возможности, очень прошу направьте меня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вы работаете с транзакциями? В идеале транзакции должны быть минимальными.
Открыли транзакцию, выполнили запрос, закоммитили транзакцию.
Если надо обработать полученные данные: открыли транзакцию, выполнили запрос, получили данные, обработали, закоммитили транзакцию.

Рекомендую не включать автокоммиты транзакций, а контролировать их самостоятельно. Тогда подобные проблемы возникать не будут.

Не надо использовать одну транзакцию для всех запросов отправляемых приложением. У меня, например, в приложении при выполнении простых запросов создается объект, в котором есть все объекты, необходимые для выполнения запроса, в том числе и IbTransaction. Таким образом для каждого запроса создается отдельная транзакция.

Погуглите "управление транзакциями в Delphi". В интернетах много материала по этому поводу.

---

**UPD**

> Благодарю, а можете подробнее описать
> момент "Рекомендую не включать
> автокоммиты транзакций"?

**AllowAutoStart** - если False, то любые попытки автоматического старта транзакций будут пресекаться. По умолчанию True.
**DefaultAction** - результат автоматического завершения транзакции в случае окончания IdleTimer - taCommit, taRollback, taCommitretaining, taRollbackretaining.Также именно этим способом будут завершены все открытые транзакции в момент вызова IBDatabase.Close (Connected:=False).
**AutoStopAction** - свойство, аналогичное DefaultAction по значениям (плюс saNone, по умолчанию), указывает на метод завершения транзакции, когда все DataSet-ы, подключенные к ней, закрываются.

Устанавливаете значения:

```
AllowAutoStart:= false;  
DefaultAction:= taCommit;  
AutoStopAction:= saNone;
```

После чего принимаете на себя управление транзакциями.  И выглядит это, примерно, так:

```
procedure TmyQuery.SQLExecute(NewQuery: string);
begin
  try
    MyTransaction.StartTransaction;  // MyTransaction типа TIbTransaction
    MyQuery.SQL.Clear;               // MyQuery типа TIBQuery
    MyQuery.SQL.Add(NewQuery);
    MyQuery.ExecSQL;
    MyTransaction.Commit;
  except
    ShowMessage('Не удалось выполнить операцию');
  end;
end;
```

где

```
type
  TmyQuery = class (TObject)
  private
    ...
    MyQuery         : TIBQuery;
    MyDataSource    : TDataSource;
    MyTransaction   : TIbTransaction;
    ...
  protected
    ...
  public
    ...
  end;
```

Строка **MyTransaction.StartTransaction;** говорит о явном открытии транзакции. Это означает, что никакие другие транзакции не будут открыты неявным образом до тех пор, пока эта не будет закоммичена. Соответственно не стоит явно открывать больше одной транзакции. Внутри одной транзакции можно выполнить сколько угодно SQL запросов, но опять же, как я говорил, транзакции должны содержать в себе минимально допустимое количество запросов. Почему? Допустим у вас в транзакции 50 запросов. Если 49 выполнились успешно, а 50й выдал ошибку, то откатятся все 50. И желательно, чтобы все запросы внутри одной транзакции были логически связаны.

---

**UPD**

> В принципе структура у меня такая же,
> только AllowAutoStart:=false; не
> использовал. Сейчас при создании формы
> поставил, но ничего не изменилось.

У вас DBGrid подключен к той же транзакции, в которой вы выполняете запросы? Просто если они на разных транзакциях, то изменений произошедшие в одной транзакции не видны компонентам, подключенным к другой транзакции, и их надо обновить вместе с транзакцией. Я сам с этим столкнулся, и сделал такой костыль (или не костыль, не знаю):

```
procedure TMyApp.UpdateTransaction(MyTransaction: TIbTransaction);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  // если предварительно не закрывать датасет, то происходит утечка памяти
  for I := 0 to IbComponents.ComponentCount-1 do
    if IbComponents.Components[i].ClassType = TIBQuery then
      if TIBQuery(IbComponents.Components[i]).Transaction = MyTransaction then
        TIBQuery(IbComponents.Components[i]).Close;

  MyTransaction.Commit;
  MyTransaction.Active:= True;

  for I := 0 to IbComponents.ComponentCount-1 do
    if IbComponents.Components[i].ClassType = TIBQuery then
      if TIBQuery(IbComponents.Components[i]).Transaction = MyTransaction then
        TIBQuery(IbComponents.Components[i]).Open;
end;
```

Comment: Благодарю, а можете подробнее описать момент "Рекомендую не включать автокоммиты транзакций"?

Comment: В принципе структура у меня такая же, только AllowAutoStart:=false; не использовал. Сейчас при создании формы поставил, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Ну тогда давайте разбираться. Я буду писать в ответ, ибо там места больше и форматирование.

Comment: 1. ДА. В свойствах DBGrid подключен к той же транзакции.
2. На сколько я понимаю в выше предоставленном коде идет переоткрытие  TIBQuery. Если так, то у меня под таймер привязан select-запрос, а с ним и переоткрытие.

Comment: давайте тогда листинг. гуща кофейная заканчивается

Comment: нашел решение: настроил транзакции, которые выполняют только select-запросы на чтение, и всё начало работать)

Спасибо за советы и затраченное время. 

Не хочу оставаться в долгах: скинь на почту (sergeev.aleksander@energosistems.com) свой номер телефона и оператор, копеечку заброшу)

Comment: Успокойся) мне самому было интересно вспомнить, что у меня там в проекте.  
Кстати у меня тоже select запросы висят на отдельных транзакциях. Почему-то забыл об этом написать...

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего новые данные не занесены, можно проверить, подключившись к базе через IbExpert(если это firebird/interbase/yaffil). Транзакция на новые данные подтверждается? Какое СУБД?

Comment: 1. как только отключаю приложение данные появляются в ibexpert, но если проверить ibexpert, не отключив приложение, то данных нет.

2. Вставку новых данных осуществляю следующим образом:
with ibq do
begin
SQL.Clear;
SQL.Add('тут запрос');
if not ibt_2.Active then ibt_2.StartTransaction;
try
ExecSQL;
ibt_2.Commit;
ShowMessage('Всё круто!'); 
except
ibt_2.Rollback;
ShowMessage('Случилась печаль!');
end;
end;

Исходя из того, что выходит сообщение 'Всё круто!' думаю, что транзакция подтверждается. А на select запрос транзакций не подключал, нужно?

3. Использую interbase 6.5

Comment: скорее всего транзакция второго приложения запущена до появления новых данных и "не видит их", аналогично в ibexpert-необходимо обновить чтобы увидеть изменения.
на select тоже есть своя транзакция,которая назначена объекту ibq

Comment: Потрясающе! Можете подробней описать ситуацию? Либо ссылку на литературу? Очень Вас прошу - уже долгое время не могу найти решение.

Comment: http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/ibtrans.htm

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Обязательно прочту, надеюсь там есть решение моей проблемы)